# How Do I assign or fetch a loop in a tab to create a gallery

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to create a gallery but I am not sure how to assign a loop in a tab. The scenario is when the year tab is click, it will load the loop  based on that year.

```
<?php if( have_rows('awards') ):  ?>
      <ul id="ytabs">
        <?php while( have_rows('awards') ): the_row(); 
            $years = get_sub_field('year'); ?>
            <li class="pagination"><?php echo $year; ?> </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
          </ul>
                <div class="award_content">     
                        
                        <?php while( have_rows('awards') ): the_row(); 
              $award_name = get_sub_field('award_name'); 
                echo $award_name;
               endwhile; ?> 
                </div>  
<?php endif;  ?>
```

Concept is similar to
https://jsfiddle.net/solodev/1c2yty3x/28/
but using loop.

Answer (score 0):

`the_row()` increments the row number each time so in between the 2 loops you have to reset the counter. There doesn't seem to be any clear way in the documentation so maybe try `acf_update_loop('active', 'i', 0);` before the second while loop.